# Compiling Qt application on Linux without X

Tags: c++, linux, qt, jenkins

In a company we have a developer server with all the necessary stuff for coding. Among others, there is a Jenkins CI tool installed and working.

Now I want to configure it to be able to build Qt5.5 application. The problem is that there are no X11 on the server - only console access.

Is it possible to build a Qt application on a platform like that? I can't even install Qt5.5 framework because of lack of the GUI. But maybe I can somehow install only required libraries and qmake?

Comment: every linux distro have a command line tool to install software, then you can install qt5 and compile your software

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine (to quote your question) to "build a Qt application on a platform like that", "installing only only required libraries and qmake".

Installing the libs will not drag a full GUI environment - else your distribution's package dependency system is seriously flawed.

What you do not state and is important too is if you want to be able to **run** a Qt application on such a platform without GUI (as opposed to "just for the jenkins build").

If this is the case, this is still possible, installing only Qt core: you'll have all the benefits of Qt's object framework, without the GUI parts. This will be a Qt console app, which is perfectly doable and legitimate.

You do not tell us what's the distribution installed on this machine, but for instance on my Debian this is the `libqt5core5a - Qt 5 core module` package:

> $ apt-cache show libqt5core5a
>
> ...
>
> Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libglib2.0-0 (>=
>   2.22.0), libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~), libpcre16-3, libstdc++6 (>= 4.9), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
>
> ...
>
> Description-en: Qt 5 core module  Qt is a cross-platform C++ application framework. Qt's primary feature  is its rich set of widgets that provide standard GUI functionality.
>
> The QtCore module contains core non-GUI functionality.
>
> ...

As you can see:

- This depends on nothing GUI related.
- This only contains core non-GUI functionality.

Comment: Thanks @jbm, to be clear: my development server is running on Centos 6. There is no X server installed, and I don't want to run my Qt application, only compile it (qmake; make all;). But I need to compile all the graphical stuff, full application. In Centos repository, we have pretty old qt packages. Is it possible to install newest Qt5.5 from official website package in console mode without the need for installing X server?

Comment: "In Centos repository, we have pretty old qt packages ... Is it possible to install newest Qt5.5 from official website package in console mode?" I don't know. But it seems the root problem here is your distro is too old compare to your app need: to a bare minimum, this jenkins server should be able to build your apps like a developer would do on his station. If this is not the case, you have a problem: the build environment on this jenkins is not representative of your development stations. This is not good, and contradict jenkins's goal in the first place.

Comment: "this jenkins server should be able to build your apps like a developer would do on his station", and I mean using the *exact* same libs that a developer would have on his station. Else, what would be the value of the jenkins "build OK/build fail" reports?